# fluid simulation controls - fluid overwhelms collision objects -

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've tried to make a tiered fountain in Blender 2.91 similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlkbeIv6kBM

However my fluid always overwhelms the structure.  I've found by trial and error that modifying the surface emission of the inflow object will reduce the amount of fluid which reduces overflow of the collision objects but I'm down to .065 and any lower, NO fluid shows up.  What are the controls that I need to use to get my fluid to arrive at a nice pace, not overflow the fountain receptacles and generally look like water?  Moby made it all look very simple but clearly it's not for me!

Is there any algorithm or heuristic for figuring this out?  I'm burning a lot of time in trial/error mode/ rebaking and I'm starting to think I will not be successful in achieving a pleasant water fountain.  Clearly Inflow surface emission is one control, inflow object size appears to be another.  Are there others?

[image: inflow]

[image: domain]

Answer (score 0):

Try raising the walls? Also, the resolution of the fluid looks very low. That could be causing problems with this. Go to the Domain, and increase the resolution divisions.